# SwiftUI Publishing from background process to main view

Tags: swift, mvvm, swiftui, observable

I'm trying to get the data from background running loop to the main view.

I can see that the counter will increment (printing in the terminal), but the view doesn't refresh the current value. The showing value is still zero for every time.

My code snippet is below:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var loop : Loop
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Content View")
            LoopView()
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct LoopView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var loop : Loop
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Loop View")
            HStack {
                Text("i = ")
                Text("\(loop.i)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
class Loop: ObservableObject {
    @Published var i: Int
    
    func startLoop() {
        while true {
            print("i = \(self.i)")
            self.i += 1
            
            sleep(1)
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.startLoop()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your `sleep` runs in fact on the main thread (`DispatchQueue.main`). If you really want to use `sleep` run it in the background use `DispatchQueue.global()`. But then you need to use `DispatchQueue.main` again to update the `@Published` variable:

```
class Loop: ObservableObject {
    @Published var i: Int

    func startLoop() {
        while true {
            print("i = \(self.i)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.i += 1
            }

            sleep(1)
        }
    }

    init() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
            self.startLoop()
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can look at repeating timers which will do the work for you:

- [How to make an action repeat using Timer](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-make-an-action-repeat-using-timer)

Comment: Just using `DispatchQueue.global()` gives rights for system to select *any* queue, so it might happen to be `main` queue again. Thus it is preferable to specify explicitly *what kind of queue* to use, ie. `background` in this case.